# One of my queries now only returns one record after working fine for 10 years - I did not change any code

Tags: mysql, arrays, while-loop

I've had a mysql database on my website for about 10 years.  I recently (5 or 6 months) ago had to upgrade to version 5.x and did so without any problems.  My database uses four tables and has been working fine until about a week ago.  One of my tables is now returning only one record even when there are many records matching the query.  I have not made any changes to the code for many years.  I have been researching this problem for several hours and have not come up with any answers and so I'm posting the code here for some help.  This code is querying a flat file with 11,549 records, each record containing 15 fields.

```
<?php   

mysql_connect ('localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock', 'my_user_name', 'my_password') or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db (virtualc_sac);
$result = mysql_query ("select * from doublestar
                        where con = '$con' and sep > '$sep1' and sep < '$sep2' 
                        group by 'name' order by '$order'");

echo ("<tr><td colspan='14' align='center'><font face='arial, helvetica' size='2'>
       <b>Search Results for<br> 
       Constellation=$con and Separation > $sep1 arc minutes
       and Separation < $sep2 arc minutes, Sorted by $order</b><br><br></td></tr>");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "<tr><td width='10'></td>

    <td width='470' colspan='14' align='left'><font face='arial, helvetica' size='2'>Sorry, no records were found. Try altering your selection criteria. Hitting the BACK button on your browser will show you your previous selection criteria.</td>";

} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       { 
           echo "<tr>
                     <td width='80' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Name
                     </td>
                     <td width='50' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Star
                     </td>
                     <td width='50' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>RA
                     </td>
                     <td width='50' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Dec
                     </td>
                     <td width='30' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Comp
                     </td>
                     <td width='50' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Mag1
                     </td>
                     <td width='50' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Mag2
                     </td>
                     <td width='30' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Sep
                     </td>
                     <td width='30' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>PA
                     </td>
                     <td width='60' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>U2000
                     </td>
                     <td width='30' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Spec
                     </td>
                     <td width='240' align='left' valign='bottom'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>Notes
                     </td>";

           echo "<tr>
                     <td width='80' align='left' valign='top'>
                         <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["name"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["star"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["ra"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["decl"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='30' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["comp"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["mag1"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["mag2"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='30' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["sep"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='30' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["pa"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='60' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["u2000"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='30' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["spec"];
           echo "</td>";
           echo "<td width='240' align='left' valign='top'>
                     <font face='arial, helvetica' size='1'>";
           echo $row["notes"];
           echo "</td></tr>"; 
       }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried group by name order by $order without quotes?

Comment: Have you checked the database to make sure the data isn't lost or corrupted?

Comment: Apart from this, your table HTML seems quite broken. Things like `</td></td>` (maybe you meant `<td /><td />`), unclosed `<font>` tags, all sorts of problems. Maybe your browser got an update and now it doesn't display this HTML correctly omitting everything but first column - just a wild guess.

Comment: I have not tried grouping by name order using $order without quotes.  Since posting this question, I've found my other queries are not properly sorting so maybe that's related to the $order having quotes.

Comment: I have checked the table and it seems fine.

Comment: I did not realize the HTML had problems and will start working on cleaning that up.  I have many users of this db and two of them reported the initial problem to me within the last couple of weeks.  All three of us are using different browsers and different operating systems so I still don't understand why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: I tried taking the quotes out $order and that changed nothing.

Comment: On the the comment from julkiewicz, </td></td> (maybe you meant <td /><td />) - I don't understand. I thought I closed a <td> with a </td> (there was a redundant </td> in my code which I removed. Also, it said there were "all sorts of problems". Could you please be more specific? I did notice that I created the table before the php script - would that cause a problem?

Comment: @Duane - If you do a "View Source" in the browser do you see the missing records anywhere?

Comment: to clarify: you had to upgrade to v5.x of... MySQL or PHP? And what was the version prior to that? If the upgrade is relevant to the problem, please clarify these points by editing the question.

Comment: @Duane - Re the comments about HTML problems: Use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the validity of your HTML code. It will tell you about any HTML errors you have.

Comment: View source shows no records.  I checked a page that is working properly and view source there shows no records.

Comment: I had to upgrade to v5.x of mysql.  I'm a novice programmer and until today had done virtually no mysql or php programming since putting up this site 10 years ago.  I don't know if the upgrade is relevant - that's why I'm posting questions here.

Comment: I used the W3C Validator and found multiple errors.  I'm thinking I need a better editor than just gedit since I'm having so many coding problems.  What do people here use for html/php/mysql?

Comment: @DuaneFrybarger "All sorts of problems" generally meant that you have either spare closing tags, or missing closing tags. I don't think a better editor will help you with generating HTML using `echo`s. A templating engine solution would or just a more consistent code formatting for that matter.

Comment: @DuaneFrybarger Have you connected to MySQL on a shell using the same credentials and performing the exact same query?

Comment: @DuaneFrybarger Also maybe it would be useful to print the actual number of rows returned by `mysql_num_rows($result)` somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

@DuaneFrybarger I would start by making sure your database is ok. Personally, my favorite tool is [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/), and use the SQL tab to type in your query and run it. If all of the records come up as expected, then the database is ok. If not, then run a simple `SELECT * ...` query to make sure all of the records are there. If all of this goes ok, then you need to go through all of your HTML again. Some other thoughts:

1. your code to create the row of headings is inside the while-loop - do you want a header row for each record?
2. there's an extra `</td>` as mentioned previously right after `echo $row["decl"];`
3. are the variables assigned earlier in your script from `$_POST`-variables?

Comment: I found it.  I had misunderstood the suggestion by nick rulez to remove the quotes from name order by $order.  When I changed group by 'name' order to group by name order, it solved the problem.  Still no idea why it would work for 10 years and then stop but I guess my isp made an update to either the mysql or php to cause this problem.  Thanks to everyone for their suggestions and support.